# String concatenation and Optional(value) being printed

Tags: ios, swift, string-concatenation

I wanted to create a function that would get the current Date, divided it in components(.year, .month, .day) to concatenate it inside a `var integrationKey`.
The problem is, whenever I call `print (chave())` I get this `sL8xlbkw2Optional(364)kLx3i832190461000160Lxd5yV0Optional(45)sKc3gHx9Optional(347)`printed on the log.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dia: Int!
    var mes: Int!
    var ano: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     print (chave())
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func chave () -> (String){

        //Pega data atual
        let currentDate = Date()

        //Pega calendario do usuarios
        let userCalendar = Calendar.current

        //Array de compnentes necessarios
        let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [
        .year,
        .month,
        .day
        ]

        //Pega os componentes
        let dateComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: currentDate)

        //componentes disponiveis

        dia = dateComponents.day! + 37
        mes = dateComponents.month! + 335
        ano = dateComponents.year! - 1652



        var chaveDeIntegracao = "sL8xlbkw2\(ano)kLx3i832190461000160Lxd5yV0\(dia)sKc3gHx9\(mes)"

        //return chaveDeIntegracao
        return chaveDeIntegracao
    }




    func chave () -> (String){

            //Pega data atual
            let currentDate = Date()

            //Pega calendario do usuarios
            let userCalendar = Calendar.current

            //Array de compnentes necessarios
            let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [
            .year,
            .month,
            .day
            ]

            //Pega os componentes
            let dateComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: currentDate)

            //componentes disponiveis

            dia = dateComponents.day! + 37
            mes = dateComponents.month! + 335
            ano = dateComponents.year! - 1652



            var chaveDeIntegracao = "sL8xlbkw2\(ano)kLx3i832190461000160Lxd5yV0\(dia)sKc3gHx9\(mes)"

            //return chaveDeIntegracao
            return chaveDeIntegracao
        }
```

And here is what was printed on the console:
`sL8xlbkw2Optional(364)kLx3i832190461000160Lxd5yV0Optional(45)sKc3gHx9O`

The question is, will these Optionals appear whenever i call this function and what about the () surrounding the values?

Comment: you want out put like this 
sL8xlbkw2364kLx3i832190461000160Lxd5yV045sKc3gHx9O
?

Comment: Yep, what did i do wrong there?

Comment: You did nothing wrong here.. its just that your question has a possible answer in the link mentioned above as duplicate.. you can check there.

Comment: replace this line 
 var chaveDeIntegracao = "sL8xlbkw2\(ano!)kLx3i832190461000160Lxd5yV0\(dia!)sKc3gHx9\(mes!)"

Comment: I could not really understand what was explained on that other link. but it helped, i think.

Comment: Optionals are described on the first page (The Basics) in the Swift Language Guide... so it means, that you never read it...